# macOS環境での Pythonのmultiprocessingについて

Tags: python, python3, macos, python-multiprocessing

以下のコードをGoogle Colabでやるとすぐ終わるのですが、Macのローカル環境でJupyter Notebookを使うと相当長い時間かかります(というか数時間経っても終わりません)。
原因を教えていただければ幸いです。

なお、Pythonのバージョンは3.8、Macのバージョンは11.2.3でM1ではありません。

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(1) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: Pythonのバージョン, できれば macOSバージョンなどの情報も質問に書き加えてもらうと, もしかすると解決の糸口になるかもしれません。あと M1かどうかも … (`set_start_method('spawn')` (あるいは別の開始方式)で動作が変わる可能性もあります)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。Pythonのバージョンは3.8で、マックのバージョンは11.2.3です。

Comment: M1ではないです。

Comment: 参考: [pythonのmultiprocessingが動きません｜teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/266783)

Comment: ありがとうございます！これが問題みたいですね。。。